# Problems when calling a PiCloud function from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to both GAE and PiCould, and have some basic questions when I would like to call a published function from GAE. It seems like my approach of calling a published function is not recognized. So can you give me some suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: I am not sure why people think this question is not valuable. My standing point is that since GAE only accept pure-Python file, it is necessary to find a way for models written in other langurages (i.e., Fortran77). Thus, some non-Python programs can be uploaded to other cloud servers such like PiCloud and then called by GAE. With people's help (thank you!) I have figured out this issue. I have attached my codes below for other's reference:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import webapp2 as webapp
import json
import base64
#import urllib2
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

api_key='1111'
api_secretkey='adsad'

####define and publish a function######
def square(x):
    """Returns square of a number"""
    print 'Squaring %d' % x
    return x*x

cloud.setkey(api_key, api_secretkey)
cloud.rest.publish(square, "square_func")

url = 'https://' + 'api.picloud.com/r/3303/square_func' 
input_val=22

#######call the function################# 
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (api_key, api_secretkey))[:-1]
http_headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' % base64string}
data = urllib.urlencode({"x":input_val})
response = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers)

jid= json.loads(response.content)['jid']
output_st = 'queued'
#
while output_st=="queued":
    response_st = urlfetch.fetch(url='https://api.picloud.com/job/?jids=%s&field=status' %jid, headers=http_headers)
    output_st = str(json.loads(response_st.content)['info']['%s' %jid]['status'])

url_val = 'https://api.picloud.com/job/result/?jid='+str(jid)
response_val = urlfetch.fetch(url=url_val, method=urlfetch.GET, headers=http_headers)
output_val = json.loads(response_val.content)['result']


class Page(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = """<table width="600" border="1">
                          <tr>
                            <th width="480" scope="col">Outputs</div></th>
                            <th width="120" scope="col">Value</div></th>                            
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Input</td>
                            <td>%s</td></tr>                          
                          <tr>
                            <td>picloud jid</td>
                            <td>%s</td></tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>picloud status</td>
                            <td>%s</td></tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>picloud results</td>
                            <td>%s</td></tr>                             
                         </table>"""%(input_val, jid, output_st, output_val)

        self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', Page)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think you're being downvoted because your question isn't relevant, but rather because you haven't actually told us what the problem is, or provided us with a stacktrace or other debugging information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line should be:

```
output_val = json.loads(response.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to output_val = json.load(response.content), but it is the same error...

ERROR 2012-03-26 15:47:23,890 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\th\Dropbox\t-picloud\main.py", line 28, in <module>
output_val = json.load(response)

File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 274, in load return loads(fp.read(),

AttributeError: '_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @thong: You are having problems with basic API reading.  In addition to the error @Shay fixed for you, you are also improperly using the `json` module. In particular, `json.load()` expects a file-like object, but `urlfetch.fetch` [returns a string](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py&q=urlfetch%20package:http://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=250).  I suggest you take a step back and read up on the APIs you wish to use. The correct `json` method to use is `loads`.

Comment: @bernie: Thanks for the clarification. All I did about calling a published model followed PiCloud document... here is the link http://docs.picloud.com/rest.html#query-format

Comment: And that is a perfect example of why you should *never* use code without first understanding it. More specifically, `urllib2` != `urlfetch`.

Comment: update:
I am able to receive some "feedback" from the published functions using output_val = json.loads(response.content)

Here is what I got, but still does not have the results of my function...
{u'output_encoding': u'json', u'description': u'Returns square of a number', u'signature': u'square_func(x)', u'uri': u'https://api.picloud.com/r/3303/square_func', u'label': u'square_func'}

Comment: @bernie: I understand that urlfetch is designed for google app engine. Since this website is hosted by GAE, I have to use it. However, the documents provided by PiCloud is really confusing and bad, especially to a non-CS person...

Comment: @thong it should be loads not load

Comment: @bernie, Shay Erlichmen, thanks for both of you. I have figured out this issue, and updated the post.

Comment: @thong: I apologize for getting a little upset earlier. I am glad you got it working. Good job! And thank you for your comment. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: @bernie Never mind. Without your help, I could not figure it out.